# How to check if a user is in a OU in Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to know if a specific user is member of a specific OU.

Comment: Use [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) and check the `DistinguishedName` property.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-SearchBase` parameter with the [`Get-ADUser` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) from the ActiveDirectory RSAT module to narrow your query to a specific subtree:

```bsh
$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'lmontoya'" -SearchBase "OU=TargetOU,DC=domain,DC=tld"
```

Beware that it will default to a recursive subtree search by default, so if you need to test whether the user is present *directly* under that OU (as opposed to just somewhere under the OU), you need to specify a `-SearchScope` as well:

```bsh
$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'lmontoya'" -SearchBase "OU=TargetOU,DC=domain,DC=tld" -SearchScope OneLevel
```

If the user isn't found with the specified criteria, `$ADUser` will be empty

The `SearchBase`/`SearchScope` parameters work with all the query cmdlets in the module, so you can use the same approach for computers or OUs or whatever else you need to find in a specific container:

```bsh
# Query all the computer account objects residing at "OU=TargetOU,DC=domain,DC=tld"
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TargetOU,DC=domain,DC=tld" -SearchScope OneLevel
```